# How to play default sound for SMS messages?

Tags: android, audio, sms, default

I can´t find how to play default sound which is set already as notification for incoming SMS.

Thank you for any advice in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_SOUND) ?

Comment: Yes, until now I uset this default sound, but this is sound of notification, and if I am not wrong, SMS message has own sound (which can be different from notification sound). I wish to use sound set for SMS, not for notifications.

Answer (score -3):

You can record this sound and then put audio file into your project

Comment: Thank you, but it must be universal, it means if somebody else use own SMS tone, I would like to be able check it and use it for my app. I need this because my app control incoming messages and I want to alert use with default tone (which can be different for each user).